# creating new columns for unique events and then counting events in R by group

Tags: r, time-series, uniqueidentifier, data-management

A subset of my data looks like this but with many more groupings (IDs):

```
 ID                          time                class    
   <chr>                       <dttm>              <fct>    
 1 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-01 19:03:31 migrating
 2 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-04 22:03:33 migrating 
 3 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-07 18:03:34 migrating 
 4 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-08 21:03:34 stopover 
 5 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-10 21:03:39 stopover 
 6 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-14 18:03:37 migrating 
 7 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-17 06:04:08 migrating 
 8 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-18 06:04:08 stopover 
 9 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-19 00:03:41 winter 
10 BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4 2022-11-27 00:03:51 winter 
11 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-14 11:00:08 migrating
12 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-15 13:59:45 stopover
13 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-20 02:59:54 stopover
14 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-21 03:00:14 migrating
15 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-21 16:59:47 stopover
16 LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3 2022-01-22 16:59:45 winter
```

I am trying to create unique columns either through `mapping` or `group_by` and `mutate` but I don't know where to begin. I would like several new columns describing unique sequential events, their sum, and their duration. New columns added to the dataframe I would suspect would look something like this:

```
newcols <- data.frame(unique_class = c("migrating1", "migrating1", "migrating1", "stopover1", 
                                       "stopover1", "migrating2", "migrating2", "stopover2", 
                                       "winter1", "winter1", "migrating1", "stopover1", 
                                       "stopover1", "migrating2", "stopover2", "winter1"),
                      migrate_sum = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                      stopover_sum = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                      winter_sum = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                      event_duration = c(6,6,6,2,2,3,3,0,8,8,0,5,5,0,0,0))
```

...where event_duration column would equate to time in days or hours. I know I need to `group_by(ID)` but and `mutate()` but not sure how to get the unique classes or lagged duration of times for each class. Any help appreciated.

NOT SURE WHERE TO PUT THIS SO EDITING MY QUESTION: I TRIED @AKRUN SOLUTION BUT IT DIDN'T QUITE WORK. IT PRODUCED THE UNIQUE_CLASS WELL BUT SUMMARIES ARE NOT INCORRECT. HERE'S AN EXAMPLE OF A DATAFRAME PRODUCED USING SOLUTION BELOW AND SUBSET BY UNIQUE ID: `fall_mig2 %>% filter(BirdsID_season == "BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4") %>% select(BirdsID_season, x, y, time, unique_class, class, stopover_sum) slice_head <-  fall_mig2 %>% filter(BirdsID_season == "BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4") %>% slice_head(n = 10) slice_tail <- fall_mig2 %>% filter(BirdsID_season == "BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4") %>% slice_tail(n = 10) bind_rows(slice_head, slice_tail) %>% select(BirdsID_season, x, y, time, stopover_sum)` and the result:

```
 BirdsID_season                  x     y time                unique_class class     stopover_sum
   <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>        <chr>            <int>
 1 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-09 19:09:01 migrating1   migrating            3
 2 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-09 21:08:36 migrating1   migrating            3
 3 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-09 23:08:55 migrating1   migrating            3
 4 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 01:09:11 migrating1   migrating            3
 5 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 03:08:50 migrating1   migrating            3
 6 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 05:09:06 migrating1   migrating            3
 7 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 07:08:43 migrating1   migrating            3
 8 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 09:08:54 migrating1   migrating            3
 9 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 11:09:07 migrating1   migrating            3
10 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -99.2  48.1 2022-11-10 13:08:39 migrating1   migrating            3
11 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-13 23:08:30 winter1      winter               1
12 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 01:08:45 winter1      winter               1
13 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 03:08:45 winter1      winter               1
14 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 05:08:26 winter1      winter               1
15 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 07:08:22 winter1      winter               1
16 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 09:08:45 winter1      winter               1
17 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 11:08:54 winter1      winter               1
18 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 13:08:19 winter1      winter               1
19 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.3  36.7 2022-12-14 15:08:47 winter1      winter               1
20 BBR-b432021-M_fall_winter_4 -89.4  36.7 2022-12-14 17:08:19 winter1      winter               1
```

`stopover_sum` should be 1 (which is in the middle of the subsetted df)
. I'm not sure where the 3 is coming from. Trying to dissect the solution now.

Comment: The second chunk of code shows the additional columns added to the original data which would be the expected output. So the expected output would include column names `id`, `time`, `class`, `class_unique`, `migrate_sum`, `stopover_sum`, `winter_sum`, `event_duration`

Comment: Yes, `newcols` was based on the original data shown in code chunk 1. I just don't know how to get from A to B. I calculated `newcols` by hand looking at the sample data

Comment: If the data.frame was grouped by ID, there would be 2 "migrating" events for each unique ID. Same with stopover (2 unique events). However there's only one "winter" event for each unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create a run-length-id column grouped by 'Class', convert the 'time' to `Date` class, then grouped by 'ID', 'class', get the number of distinct (`n_distinct`) elements in 'grp', as well as the `unique_class` is created by `paste`ing the 'class' with the `unique` 'grp' indexes. Do a second grouping by 'ID', 'unique_class' to calculate the 'event_duration' ie. the number of days between the `max/min` 'date' values, select the columns of interest, reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider` and `fill` the values in the `_sum` to previous non-NA values

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(grp = rleid(class), date = as.Date(ymd_hms(time))) %>% 
   group_by(ID, class) %>% 
   mutate(Count = n_distinct(grp), 
     unique_class = str_c(class, match(grp, unique(grp)))) %>% 
   group_by(ID, unique_class) %>% 
   mutate(event_duration = as.integer(max(date) - min(date))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   transmute(rn = row_number(), class = str_c(class, '_sum'),
    Count, unique_class, event_duration) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = Count) %>% 
   fill(ends_with("_sum"), .direction = "downup") %>% 
   select(-rn) %>%
   relocate(event_duration, .after = last_col())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   unique_class migrating_sum stopover_sum winter_sum event_duration
   <chr>                <int>        <int>      <int>          <int>
 1 migrating1               2            2          1              6
 2 migrating1               2            2          1              6
 3 migrating1               2            2          1              6
 4 stopover1                2            2          1              2
 5 stopover1                2            2          1              2
 6 migrating2               2            2          1              3
 7 migrating2               2            2          1              3
 8 stopover2                2            2          1              0
 9 winter1                  2            2          1              8
10 winter1                  2            2          1              8
11 migrating1               2            2          1              0
12 stopover1                2            2          1              5
13 stopover1                2            2          1              5
14 migrating2               2            2          1              0
15 stopover2                2            2          1              0
16 winter1                  2            2          1              0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4",
 "BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", 
"BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", "BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", 
"BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", "BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", 
"BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", "BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", 
"BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", "BBR-b172021-M_fall_winter_4", 
"LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3", "LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3", 
"LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3", "LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3", 
"LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3", "LINWR-b1282020-M_fall_winter_3"
), time = c("2022-11-01 19:03:31", "2022-11-04 22:03:33", "2022-11-07 18:03:34", 
"2022-11-08 21:03:34", "2022-11-10 21:03:39", "2022-11-14 18:03:37", 
"2022-11-17 06:04:08", "2022-11-18 06:04:08", "2022-11-19 00:03:41", 
"2022-11-27 00:03:51", "2022-01-14 11:00:08", "2022-01-15 13:59:45", 
"2022-01-20 02:59:54", "2022-01-21 03:00:14", "2022-01-21 16:59:47", 
"2022-01-22 16:59:45"), class = c("migrating", "migrating", "migrating", 
"stopover", "stopover", "migrating", "migrating", "stopover", 
"winter", "winter", "migrating", "stopover", "stopover", "migrating", 
"stopover", "winter")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, looks like the solution may have been a little more complicated than I thought--I haven't seen some of those functions used before. I think it worked but I think the solution needs `bind_rows` to original dataframe?

Comment: @NickMasto I was only looking at your expected output.  which didn't show you added into the original data.  So, I used `transmute` to only select coumns of interest.  With the current soluiton, you can use `%>% bind_cols(df1, .)` at the end

Comment: Sorry, `bind_cols`, not rows. However, `transmutate` disorganizes the data and so the sums are incorrect because its not grouped by ID. So I don't think the fix would be to `%>%bind_cols(df1, .)` right? I could be wrong for sure.

Comment: @NickMasto The `_sum` is created as reshaped column name, otherwise, it is the `Count`, column, which is grouped by your 'ID' and 'class'.  So, itshouldn't have any problem.  Also, transmute returns the same number of rows as mutate, therefore, it is also not an issue.  I created row sequence as well to keep the original number of rows while reshaping

Comment: Immensely helpful. Thankyou @akrun. It indeed has the same number of observations and everything appears to be in order in terms of summation and durations. The only thing I changed was `mutate(event_duration = difftime(max(time), min(time), units = "days"))` to get more accurate duration based on appropriate tz.

Comment: @NickMasto Yes, I was also initially working with `difftime`, but then, I thought, it is much easier on the Date class

Comment: Okay last comment/question. By using pivot wider to get column sums, you got rid of the column `class`. Is there anyway to keep that column whilst still pivoting with it?

Comment: I found a workaround to keep `class` for future analyses by `mutate(class = str_sub(unique_class, start = 1, end = -2`. Thanks again @akrun

Comment: @NickMasto When you do the `bind_cols`, you have the original column, right?

Comment: No class was deleted following `bind_cols` which I presumed was because of `pivot_wider`

Comment: @NickMasto I removed it by using `transmute` (returns only those columns that are selected in transmute) as I thought you don't want that column

Comment: Going through each uniqueID, the above solution did not work perfectly. The columns stopover_sum and migrating_sum etc. should be the same for each uniqueID but they are not. For example I isolated a bird to take a look like so `df %>% filter(ID == "uniqueID") %>% dplyr::select(x,y,time unique_class, class, stopover_sum)` and there were different integers. I edited my answer to show the unique df I'm talking about.

Comment: fyi the problem arises w/ the addition of `bind_cols(df, .)`.

Comment: Oh boy. Okay, so I've tried it on several different IDs now. The problem actually arises when filling NAs. Simply removing the line `fill(ends_with("_sum"), .direction = "downup")` gives me expected results on all uniqueIDs tested. I edited my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Again thank you @akrun. My question/intended output was a poorly worded; you're solution did exactly what I asked. I should have specified that I wanted to retain the entire dataset. To do so, I adjusted your solution with `mutate` instead of `transmute` and added duration columns, using the same `pivot_wider` procedure. I duplicated `class` and `event_duration` columns so I could retain them. Admittedly, quite clumsy but effective nonetheless. Thanks again. Below should be the final solution:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(grp = data.table::rleid(class), 
         date = as.Date(ymd_hms(time))) %>% 
  group_by(ID, class) %>% 
  mutate(count = n_distinct(grp), 
         unique_class = str_c(class, match(grp, unique(grp)))) %>% 
  group_by(ID, unique_class) %>% 
  mutate(event_duration = difftime(max(time), min(time), units = "days")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(class = str_c(class, '_sum')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = count) %>% 
  relocate(event_duration, .after = last_col()) %>%
  mutate(class = str_sub(unique_class, start = 1, end = -2),
         class2 = class,
         event_duration2 = event_duration) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = class2, values_from = event_duration2) %>%
  mutate(mig_dur = migrating,
         stop_dur = stopover,
         winter_dur = winter) %>%
  dplyr::select(-migrating, -stopover, -winter)
```